# Issue with overflow-x: auto while using pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, pseudo-element

I am currently designing a timeline in CSS. It has a `<section>` element with the class "timeline" which should always be 100% width. On smaller devices the content should scroll horizontally inside the `<section>`. I wanted to use `overflow-x: auto` but apparently this does not work.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fj0748sevpzoque/Screenshot%202015-02-11%2015.44.29.png?dl=0

This is the result when applying `overflow-x: auto` to ".timeline". I also tried adding `white-space: nowrap` but it does not make any difference. There are lots of `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements which probably makes it harder.

You can look at the code here: http://codepen.io/jonicious/pen/NPXYKV

I would be very happy if you take some time and may help me to fix that. (Positioning and overall design is not final.) Thanks in advice! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a min-width to your section if you want it to not adjust to smaller screen sizes:

```
min-width:1000px;
```

Replace the 1000px with the minimum size you need.

http://codepen.io/jonicious/pen/NPXYKV

Comment: I want it work on smaler screen sizes but that it scrolls inside the div like in this example: http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/photo-galleries/css-horizontal-scroller1-demo.php

And the problems seems to be something with `overflow` which I need to achieve that.

Comment: Wrap your ul in a new div to achive that. Give that new div a min-width, an your ul a min-width that is higher: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogpdWr

Comment: Also, I don't know why but the codepen you linked is now a bit broken, it looked different before.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. With your solution it scrolls horizontally but also vertical :(

Comment: That's because your ul is actually only 18px high ( the blue line ) the rest gets added by before & after. Move the div outside of the timeline and give it a height: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPJemy

Comment: Also remember: if you want the blue line to have the same length as your box, you will need to give it the same min-width as your ul, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJVqLw